# APNS not return error message when push to invalid device token?

Tags: ios, token, device

I am iOS developer. I have 1 issue and would like to get your advise!

This is:

- I am using my iPhone install my app to get device_token_1.
- Then i uninstall and reinstall the app to get new device_token_2.
- Now on server side, i push APNS to device_token_1 & device_token_2.

Expect:

- Push to device_token_1 will be get error message
- Push to device_token_2 will be success.

But actually:

- Push to device_token_1 success (no error message)
- Push to device_token_2 success.

Anyone can help me on this issue?

Thanks & Regards,

Anthony

Comment: instead of uploading everytime new device token to server from phone you just update the Old device token with respect to your device [Unique iD or use keychain access in device]

Comment: Did you solve this?